# Looking for old anime with twin brothers fighting their evil wizard father

Tags: genma-wars

I am looking for an old anime that I found sometime ago but whose name I have forgotten. Keep in mind that I only saw the first episode but here are the details that I remember of the plot and parts of the first episode I saw.

The story takes place on a world (that may or may not be earth), more specifically on an island, where an evil wizard, along with other wizards, and his anthropomorphic-like animal servants rule over a primitive humanity enslaving them as they live in terror.

This evil wizard was searching for a worthy heir to replace him as a wizard and while ignoring his own wife, he began raiding nearby human villages for beautiful women who he then rapes to produce a son worthy of him.

The first episode begins when in a dark castle the most recent heir is fighting in a arena to prove himself worthy of joining the wizards demonstrating superhuman strength but no magic. When he won the evil wizard, his father, entered his mind and when the boy couldn't resist him having not enough magic to do so, the evil wizard killed him. The boy's trainer tried to protest this later in the wizard's chamber but he ended up angering the evil wizard and he turned the trainer into a talking wolf.

Later the evil wizard sent an army to raid yet another human village, over the disgusted protest of his wife, when to his surprise a young red headed woman stood up to the army. She offered herself to the wizard in exchange that her family and the rest of her village are left unharmed. The wizard keeps his bargain and the trainer, now a wolf, takes the girl to the wizard's castle where she is later raped by the evil wizard. After being taken to a cave outside the castle she gives birth to two red headed twins (I forget the names she gives them but one of them had slightly pointed ears). The wolf takes the pointed ear twin and delivers him to the castle and the mother keeps the other.

That's where the episode more or less ends but there is one other detail I remember that should help. During the episode the evil wizard's wife was begging the moon (the name of the deity that shares the name of the title of the anime) to cure her husband of his madness. The moon answered with visions of the two boys.

Also the anime was English dubbed with sub-English option.

I realize that with all this detail it shouldn't be difficult to find yet I have been unable to find it myself and I can't remember the name of it so if anyone knows what this anime is could you please tell me.

Comment: Mhm... Blue exorcist?? Got the brothers Err I don't know, I might be wrong ;-;

Answer (score 3):

It's probably [Genma Wars](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1705/Genma_Taisen:_Shinwa_Zenya_no_Shou), which is based on the manga called [Genma Taisen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genma_Taisen). It seems to fit your description of the plot and characters (twin brothers, wizard father, kidnapped mother, etc) perfectly. Cheers!

[image]

> In the distant future, monsters and inhumans roam the land, and the ruling Evil King seeks a human woman to bear him powerful, force-adept heirs. Non offers herself to the Evil King in order to save her village from Ape Clan raiders, and gives him twin sons, Loof and Jin. She and her sons are exiled by the ungrateful villagers, however, and Non's companion Nue (a Demon Clan member changed into a wolf for disobedience) takes Loof to be raised by his father, the Evil King. The Evil One's Queen Parome despises humans, however, and her malevolence towards Loof deepens...

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. Can you please expand on you answer by providing a short summary of the series and/or how it matches to what is asked? currently as the answer stands it's a link only answer where the link goes to Youtube which videos can be taken down without warning. without extra information this answer risks becoming invalid